# Remove index.php AND trailing slashes from URL

Tags: .htaccess

I've got the following rewrite rules in my .htaccess, the first 4 lines are supposed to deal with allowing to access the site without index.php, and works fine, until I add the last bit which I'm trying to use to remove trailing slashes from the sites URLs.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(uploads|cache|themes|default|admin\.php|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1

# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I add the last line, and I visit the  root of my site, the index.php part gets appended to the URL, why is this?

Answer (score 2):

> When I add the last line, and I visit the root of my site, the index.php part gets appended to the URL, why is this?

This is because the rules are applied sequentially. You want the redirect to happen *before* you route stuff to `/index.php`. Just swap those rules around:

```
# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(uploads|cache|themes|default|admin\.php|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1  [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following rules are work for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Removing trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]

#Removing index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=302,NE,L]
```